# Check if image exists via jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This script uses an API to access information from a database and displays a 'spotlight' for a random person in the db that includes their name, a photo, and a short bio.

I'm trying to write this script to check if the image exists.  If the image exists, then the script should continue, but if the image doesn't exists (404 error) it should reroll and check again.  I'm having issues understanding how to work with the asynchronous part of ajax.

```
        function checkImage(imgurl){
           function headRequest(url){
               return $.ajax({  //Makes a HEAD request for the image
                   url: url,
                   type: 'HEAD'
               });
            };
            headRequest(imgurl)
            .done(function(){
                return true; //image exists
             })
            .fail(function(){
                return false; //HEAD request returns 404
             });
        };

    //if image does not exist or person.biography is undefined, reroll
    while (!checkImage(imgsrc) || person.biography == undefined) {
        //select random person
    }
```

Comment: why not use recursion?

Comment: You should read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: @HorsSujet Yeah, I've been looking that over, but I'm having trouble understanding the callback aspect.

Comment: In this case you should not have to use a while loop.  If you fail, you just call checkImage again with another "roll".

Comment: The question I have here is what happens when there are no valid "rolls"?  Do you want a limit on how many times that you reroll?

Comment: @deweyredman  At this point, there isn't a need to limit rerolls.

Answer (score 2):

Got to use a callback! (You can't return from an `async` call)

```
function checkImage(imgurl, callback){
       function headRequest(url){
           return $.ajax({  //Makes a HEAD request for the image
               url: url,
               type: 'HEAD'
           });
        };
        headRequest(imgurl)
        .done(function(){
            callback(true); //image exists
         })
        .fail(function(){
            callback(false); //HEAD request returns 404
         });
 };
```

And call the function:

```
checkImage(imgsrc, function(exists) {
    //exists is what you passed into the callback
    if (exists) { //do stuff

    } else {
        //doesnt
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to use the jquery ajax success and error callback functions, as well as setting async to false, but the loop is still going?

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkImage(imgurl, callback){
       function headRequest(url){
           return $.ajax({
               url: url,
               type: 'HEAD'
           });
        };
        headRequest(imgurl)
        .done(function(){
            //Do whatever you wanted to do after it successfully found
            callback(imgurl);
         })
        .fail(function(){
            var newRandom = GetNewRandom(): //get your new random person url
            checkImage(newRandom, callback);  //Try again
         });
    };
```

So this way it keep iterating through calls until it locates a match.  For example, maybe it would be run like this:

```
var firstPerson = GetNewRandom();  //Initial person
function myCallback(url) {
    $('#myImage').attr('src', url);  //Change src to successful image
}
checkImage(firstPerson, myCallback); //starting with this person, look for a match
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up setting the asynchronous portion to false.  I know it's not good practice, but this is the best solution for the interim.

```
    function checkImage(imgurl){
        function headRequest(url){
            var http = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "HEAD",
                async: false
            })
            return http.status;
        }
        if(headRequest(imgurl) == 200) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    //if image does not exist or person.biography is undefined, reroll
    while (!checkImage(imgsrc) || person.biography == undefined) {
        //reroll
    }
```